# JSON nested classed, parent reference

Tags: c#, json, json.net

i'm trying to deserialize some JSON into objects it works perfectly .. almost ...

i'm using the NewtonSoft.Json lib in C#

i have a serie of nested classes.

For example:

```
class car (string prop, string prop2}
```

within the car class a nested class wheel

```
class wheel {string prop, car Parent}
```

now i want to get a reference from the wheel class to the car (Parent) class
the DeserializeObject works good, is deserializing all the object and nested objects

```
Car c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Car>(jsonString);
```

but it seems impossible to get a reference the parent class :( ?

Answer (score 2):

fixed!

```
{   
    "$id":"1",
    "id":"car1",
    "name":"test",
    "description":"nice car",
    "wheel":[
        {
            "car":{"$ref":"1"},
            "name":"section",
            "description":"nice car"
        }
    ]
}
```

just added `$ref` in the JSON

Answer (score 0):

Instead of serializing and deserializing the Car object.
In you scenario, you can actually serialize and deserialize the Wheel object. In doing so, you will have the both the car and the wheel's information.

Try to deserialize the Json to Wheel object.

Comment: It only gives me the wheel object :( for example, i have the wheel object and want to access properties of the parent class (Car) Wheel.Parent.Prop2

Comment: can u provide a sample json string of a wheel object?

Comment: [
 { "id":"12345",
  "name":"name",
  "description":"this is a sample.",
  "date":"2011-08-29",
  "begins":null,
  "ends":null,
   "Wheel":[
   {"id":"4e5b55c3d2c6842cc600003a",
   "name":"The name of the wheel",
    "items":[{ "id":"4e5b55c3d2c6842cc600003b",
       "name":"Opening",
       "props":[]

Comment: whoops, sorry for the mess ..  this is perfectly deserializing i can access Car.Wheel.Items.Prop1, but if when i'm in the wheel object i want to access props from Car ..

Answer (score 0):

You can set this property on both ends (client/server) and Json.net should link the tree back together during deserialization:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All
};
```

You can pass those settings into each call to `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`, or you can set them globally using:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All;
```